# 'Binding' is not convertible to UILabel using SQLite in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

My first time around here with a Swift related question with the SQLite.Swift library.

I have a for loop for a db.prepare statement, but I am stuck when trying to assign an array value to a UILabel.

```
    // Prepare query to retrieve the message
var _phraseMessage:String = ""    
let _stmt = _db.prepare("SELECT id, message FROM messages WHERE language = 'EN' AND category = 1 and username = 'user' LIMIT 1")

            for row in _stmt {

                println("id: \(row[0]), message: \(row[1])")

                self._phraseMessageLabel = row[1] --> i get an error here **"'Binding' is not convertible to UILabel"**


            }
```

How can assign the value in `row[1]` to my UILabel? Or even better to a String variable if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Disclaimer: This is my first attempt to Swift + Third party library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set the `UILabel` property itself to your value - you want to set the `text` property *on* the label to your value:

```
self._phraseMessageLabel.text = row[1] as! String
```

If you want to assign the value to a variable:

```
var message = row[1] as! String
```

One thing to note is that with both approaches, your label text or variable will only end up being set to the value for the *last* row returned, the one that is processed last by the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Undo's fix above, I wanted to offer a couple other solutions.

1. Try using `Database.scalar` or `Statement.scalar` if you're only using a single value, as in your example above.

   ```
   // make sure to remove "id" from your SELECT statement
   self._phraseMessageLabel.text = _stmt.scalar() as! String
   ```

   > *Note*: Make sure to remove `id` from your SELECT statement; `scalar` returns the first column of the first row only.
2. Use the `Statement.row` cursor.

   ```
   _stmt.step()
   self._phraseMessageLabel.text = _stmt.row[1]
   ```